# Text align inheritance in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML structure which contains div and some CSS rules. I want to know that why `text-align:centre` is inherit to its child div and why is only `text-align:centre` is inherit

```css
.multi {
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left
}
```

```html
<div class="multi">
  <div class="rr">Abc</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In CSS, some properties are naturally inherited, by default. [`text-align`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp) is one of these, along with `font`, `color`, and others. [Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150324100731/http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=2795D) is a rather small (but mostly robust) list of properties which will be, and will *not* be, inherited by children.

What you'll have to do in this case is something like this:

```
<style>
.multi {
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
.multi .rr {
    text-align: left; /* Or whatever value multi's parent has */
}
</style>
```